# How to declare and call a function with unknown arguments?

Tags: c++, function, c++11, extern

Let's say I have a function `drawImage` that takes a lot of arguments, some of them are of WinApi types like `HWND`, `HDC` and so on; and I don't want to import all of them in my class' header. But I need to call it from my class' methods.

```
extern void drawImage();

class A {
private :
    int n;
    // ...
public :
    // ...
    void draw() {
        drawImage(n);
    }
};
```

The code above gives me the expected error: `drawImage does not take one argument`. So how could I achieve this?

Moreover, I don't want to define my member function in the source file that includes the WinApi stuff.

**UPDATE:**

```
extern void drawImage();
extern int a;
extern unsigned long int b;
...
extern "C" void c;
class A{
       private :
         int n;
        ...
      public :
       ...
       void draw(a,b,c){
        drawImage(a,b,c,n);
       }
}
```

This could make a great solution, but Visual studio does not allow `extern void` declarations.

Comment: You want to call a function that doesn't take one argument with one argument; why would you expect that to work? *How* would expect that to work?

Comment: thats my question , some magic c++ thing to allow such a flexibility in the code like  symbolic args : `draw(a,b,c,d)`

Comment: As a rule, and in this case, expecting "magic" will leave you disappointed.

Comment: its a legitimate question, so why the downvote ?!

Answer (score 2):

Simply define `void A::draw()` out-of-line, in a .cpp file (for example `A.cpp`).
There you can include the full the declaration of `drawImage`, and remove that include from `A.h`.

---

If that isn't enough, that is, you want to completely separate the WinApi stuff from your code, you just have to go one step further. Your `A.cpp` would look something like:

```
#include "A.h"

namespace winapi {
    // Wrapper function for WinApi's drawImage,
    // with the parameters we actually care about
    void apiDrawImage(int, unsigned long, int);
}

void A::draw(int a, unsigned long b) {
    apiDrawImage(a,b,n);
}
```

Then you'd implement `winapi::drawImage` in yet another .cpp file, say `winapi.cpp`:

```
// Declares the actual drawImage() function
#include <WinApiStuff.h>

namespace winapi {
    void apiDrawImage(int a, unsigned long b, int n) {
        // Forward to WinApi
        ::drawImage(/* ... */);
    }
}
```

And `winapi.cpp` will then be the only file to know about the WinApi.

Bonus point: if you compile and link with LTO enabled (`-flto` for GCC and Clang), all of this can be inlined across translation units and end up with absolutely no overhead!

Comment: that would be my last resort, but i hoped not to mix the pure WINAPI code with the pure C++ code

Comment: thanks I ended up using : `void print(void * a,int b,int c){
  drawImage(a,b,c,number);
 }` a lot more simpler :)

Comment: @NeoMosaid I'm not sure what is "simpler" apart from the lack of namespace, but as long as it suits you... :)

Comment: This does not mix the winapi code with the c++ code. You define different draw functions for each graphics engine. You hide them from the public header (unless the caller itself will provide the graphics engine, in which case obviously you must have HWND's and other things in the header).

Comment: @KennyOstrom that first comment was about the first revision to my answer, which sits above the horizontal rule (and which itself came before OP's requirement of not mixing WinApi into the implementation) :)

Comment: suggest not calling your function the same thing as the WinAPI function, because the latter are usually `#define`d